How can I improve this for loop to index specific lines of a vector with a large dataset
I apologize if this is formatted incorrectly or if I am missing any information that would be helpful. I am attempting to run a for loop with a nested if statement for a couple of large datasets. The code is:
ID_index <- data.frame()
for (x in 1:length(peaks)) {
  z <- ((mass_combo - peaks[x])/mass_combo)*10^6
  if (length(which(abs(z) < 1)) > 0) {
    ID_index[nrow(ID_index)+1, 1] <- peaks[x]
    ID_index[nrow(ID_index), 2] <- toString(which(abs(z) < 1))
  }
}

The vector peaks is a vector of length ~130,000 numerical components. The vector mass_combo is a numerical vector with over 150,000,000 components. What I am trying to do is index if each experimental value (peaks) is within a given error margin (z) of a vector of possible theoretical values (mass_combo). The theoretical values were previously calculated by taking all possible combinations of components using the expand.grid function.
I had this loop running for approximately 2 hours and the loop only went through 5700 iterations. An example of the input and output would be:
peaks <- c(178.1161, 182.0530, 186.1223)
mass_combo <- c(154.1161, 166.1161, 178.1161, 190.1161, 202.1161, 214.1161, 226.1161, 170.053, 
                182.053, 194.053, 206.053, 709.0452, 721.0452, 182.0530, 194.0530, 186.1223, 
                198.1223, 210.1223)

ID_index
V1          V2
178.1161    3
182.0530    9, 14
186.1223    16

Is there a better method I can be performing this to index and identify theoretical value matches for each experimental result? Any assistance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

After some algebra to rearrange the comparison, the operation can be implemented as a data.table non-equi join, which will be much faster than looping.
Demonstrating on the example data:
data.table(x = mass_combo)[,`:=`(min = x - x/1e6, max = x + x/1e6, r = .I)][
  data.table(y = peaks), .(peak = y, r), on = .(min < y, max > y)
][,.(idx = .(r)), peak]
#>        peak    idx
#>       <num> <list>
#> 1: 178.1161      3
#> 2: 182.0530   9,14
#> 3: 186.1223     16

Or to get the mass_combo values instead of indices, per the comments:
data.table(x = mass_combo)[,`:=`(min = x - x/1e6, max = x + x/1e6)][
  data.table(y = peaks), .(peak = y, x), on = .(min < y, max > y)
][,.(mass_combo = .(x)), peak]
#>        peak      mass_combo
#>       <num>          <list>
#> 1: 178.1161        178.1161
#> 2: 182.0530 182.053,182.053
#> 3: 186.1223        186.1223

Timing a dataset with the approximate sizes of your actual data:
peaks <- runif(13e4)
mass_combo <- runif(15e7)

system.time(
  ID_index <-
    data.table(x = mass_combo)[,`:=`(min = x - x/1e6, max = x + x/1e6, r = .I)][
      data.table(y = peaks), .(peak = y, r), on = .(min < y, max > y)
    ][,.(idx = .(r)), peak]
)
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   71.22    4.47   25.64

The first 10 rows:
ID_index[1:10]
#>           peak                                                       idx
#>          <num>                                                    <list>
#>  1: 0.54024270        267797,2733918,3335681,3499464,3800516,4405793,...
#>  2: 0.52608405        263261, 383398,1462884,1510015,2504774,2521597,...
#>  3: 0.41793366        847991,1156169,1213597,1489392,1680001,3838945,...
#>  4: 0.24143285        512967,1296863,3515676,4526957,5952832,6020254,...
#>  5: 0.89169524        285889, 785031, 829258, 966923,1044726,2564670,...
#>  6: 0.09785744 20626427,23309899,23498292,23712990,23870867,35958767,...
#>  7: 0.07118160   681958, 7164888,10311600,11386095,12753834,34130008,...
#>  8: 0.27893975       1378505,2577870,3153625,3320806,5095727,9098257,...
#>  9: 0.01651383  1503323, 5273696,27981236,30451611,42380615,42807730,...
#> 10: 0.61528940       2191889,2570098,2979545,3398146,4041039,4652609,...

Compare against a looping approach on vectors that are 10x smaller:
peaks <- runif(13e3)
mass_combo <- runif(15e6)

system.time({ # from @ThomasIsCoding
  subset(
    data.frame(
      V1 = peaks,
      V2 = unlist(
        lapply(
          peaks,
          function(x) {
            toString(which(abs(1 - x / mass_combo) < 1e-6))
          }
        ), FALSE, FALSE
      )
    ),
    nzchar(V2)
  )
})
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>  920.64  542.20 1463.61

system.time(
  data.table(x = mass_combo)[,`:=`(min = x - x/1e6, max = x + x/1e6, r = .I)][
    data.table(y = peaks), .(peak = y, r), on = .(min < y, max > y)
  ][,.(idx = .(r)), peak]
)
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    5.15    0.26    2.14


Hi @jblood94 thank you for the suggestion as well. Your solution was even faster than the previous recommendations as you also demonstrated. Thank you for the feedback and I will work to implement it into my code!

This code works very well when scaled up to the full data set! It can provide the indexes for everything within a very short period and I thank you for that.  Since this worked so well, would this be able to be modified to instead give the value that is being indexed? So in the example you provided, instead of giving the index in ID_index[,2], it instead gave the indexed value?

Getting the values is a little easier than getting the indices. See the second code block in the updated answer.

Thank you @jblood94 both versions of the code are very helpful! I appreciate the addition you made to the reply.

It is pretty well documented that growing objects in a for loop is very inefficient and the biggest source of inefficiency in your code.
Here are some things I would do to improve the speed of your for loop:

Pre-allocate memory for assignment of indexes within your tolerance

You already know the size of your output target vector: length(peaks). Use this initialize the correct size vector. This way you are not growing it within the loop.


Do not duplicate computations

In your example, you run which(abs(z) < 1) twice. Once in the if statement and once more for those that pass your conditional statement.


Do not assign if you do not have to

The first column in the data frame you are creating is just peaks. No need to build this within your for loop, just create it after the fact.



For example,
for (x in seq_along(peaks)) {
  z <- ((mass_combo - peaks[x])/mass_combo)*10^6
  idx <- which(abs(z) < 1)
  if (length(idx) > 0) {
    tol_idx[x] <- toString(idx)
  }
}
ID_index <- data.frame(peaks, tol_idx)

From here you can continue to improve by considering what remaining expressions are necessary. For example, do you need the if statement?
If none of mass_combo are within your tolerance then which() will return an empty vector and if passed to toString() that will return an empty string: "". This is the same value initialized by vector():
vector(mode = "character", length = 1L)
# [1] ""

which(c(F, F))
# integer(0)

toString(which(c(F, F)))
# [1] ""

This allows you to remove that conditional all together and boost performance:
tol_idx <- vector(mode = "character", length = length(peaks))
for (x in seq_along(peaks)) {
  z <- ((mass_combo - peaks[x])/mass_combo)*10^6
  tol_idx[x] <-  toString(which(abs(z) < 1))
}

ID_index <- data.frame(peaks, tol_idx)

Edit
From the comment made by @ThomasIsCoding, the uncertainty in the size of your output may come from only wanting to keep rows with a match. I think it is more effective to keep all observations and then filter your data frame after the fact:
ID_index <- data.frame(peaks, tol_idx)

# remove rows where tol_idx is ""
ID_index <- ID_index[nzchar(ID_index$tol_idx),] 

Benchmark
Your example is small but the time savings will scale the larger your real data. In this small example your code takes about 66% longer:
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  `LMc if` = {
    tol_idx <- vector(mode = "character", length = length(peaks))
    for (x in seq_along(peaks)) {
      z <- ((mass_combo - peaks[x])/mass_combo)*10^6
      idx <- which(abs(z) < 1)
      if (length(idx) > 0) {
        tol_idx[x] <- toString(idx)
      }
    }
    ID_index <- data.frame(peaks, tol_idx)
  },
  `LMc no if` = {
    tol_idx <- vector(mode = "character", length = length(peaks))
    for (x in seq_along(peaks)) {
      z <- ((mass_combo - peaks[x])/mass_combo)*10^6
      tol_idx[x] <-  toString(which(abs(z) < 1))
    }
    
    ID_index <- data.frame(peaks, tol_idx)
  },
  `TCB at EU` = {
    ID_index <- data.frame()
    for (x in 1:length(peaks)) {
      z <- ((mass_combo - peaks[x])/mass_combo)*10^6
      if (length(which(abs(z) < 1)) > 0) {
        ID_index[nrow(ID_index)+1, 1] <- peaks[x]
        ID_index[nrow(ID_index), 2] <- toString(which(abs(z) < 1))
      }
    }
  },
  unit = "relative"
)
Unit: relative
      expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval cld
    LMc if 1.218349 1.217380 1.561912 1.220759 1.213983 15.954036   100  ab
 LMc no if 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000  1.000000   100  a 
 TCB at EU 1.712652 1.705199 1.664062 1.702189 1.661490  1.357403   100   b

If the speed boost from these recommendations is still not enough you could consider parallel processing your iterations which would also provide a big performance boost.

I think you need to omit the rows with empty tol_idx, i.e., "", according to OP's output format. Anyway, good answer with a sound reference, +1!

Hi @LMc Thank you for the feedback and the suggestions. I am self-taught and it seems that some of the methods I have used for writing my code have been inefficient. I probably haven't noticed it due to not previously working with such large data sets. I will take your suggestions and try to implement them to improve my code! The method that @ThomasIsCoding provided ended up being the fastest method when I scaled things up to the full mass_combo size and using a larger input on peaks. Would it be ok to ask a question tomorrow on this thread if I have followups?

That's great and I hope you learn(ed) something. @ThomasIsCoding always has fast answers that you can learn a lot from by studying them closely. If you have follow ups related to this specific question or solutions given here that's fine but if your question deviates a bit from the content of this post I'd recommend posting a new question.

Considering that you are dealing with large data, you may have to loop through each peaks to obtain the desired indices (otherwise, a vectorized approach may incur some out-of-memory issues).
In your code, the part that iteratively updating the data frame by adding new rows is a slow operation
ID_index[nrow(ID_index)+1, 1] <- peaks[x]
ID_index[nrow(ID_index), 2] <- toString(which(abs(z) < 1))

which actually can be optimized by avoiding the dynamic updating.

Benchmarking Example
set.seed(0)
peaks <- rnorm(1e3, 200)
mass_combo <- rnorm(1e5, 200)


f1 <- \() {
  ID_index <- data.frame()
  for (x in 1:length(peaks)) {
    z <- ((mass_combo - peaks[x]) / mass_combo) * 10^6
    if (length(which(abs(z) < 1)) > 0) {
      ID_index[nrow(ID_index) + 1, 1] <- peaks[x]
      ID_index[nrow(ID_index), 2] <- toString(which(abs(z) < 1))
    }
  }
  ID_index
}

f2 <- \() {
  subset(
    data.frame(
      V1 = peaks,
      V2 = unlist(
        lapply(
          peaks,
          function(x) {
            toString(which(abs(1 - x / mass_combo) < 1e-6))
          }
        ), FALSE, FALSE
      )
    ),
    nzchar(V2)
  )
}

microbenchmark(
  f1 = f1(),
  f2 = f2(),
  times = 10L,
  check = "equivalent",
  unit = "relative"
)

which shows
Unit: relative
 expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
   f1 2.434582 2.506911 2.504454 2.474551 2.579847 2.497963    10
   f2 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000    10


Hi @ThomasIsCoding thank you for the reply and for the suggestions. As I mentioned to @LMc I am fairly amateurish when it comes to optimizing code and have no formal training. I appreciate your suggestion and the code that you recommended. The use of subset that you provided produced the quickest code and matching results when I scaled things up to a larger data set (peaks with 30 values and mass_combo with the full list). I will try this code on the full list of peaks when I get into work tomorrow. Would it be ok to followup on this thread tomorrow if I have any issues?

@TCBatEU no problem. If your follow-up issues deviate a lot, I suggest you open a new question ticket.

Here is another base R solution, which is interesting and fun for play, but might be suitable for small or medium datasets only.
For example, with the data peaks and mass_combo in your question, you can use outer + which + split like below
with(
    as.data.frame(which(abs(1 - outer(peaks, mass_combo, `/`)) < 1e-6, TRUE)),
    split(col, row)
)

which gives
$`1`
[1] 3

$`2`
[1]  9 14

$`3`
[1] 16

Warning!!!
The approach above doesn't apply to large data, since outer is memory-wise expensive, you may have out-of-memory issues if you may produce a titanic matrix. So, NOT RECOMMENDED for large datasets.

Hi @ThomasIsCoding, thank you for this additional suggestion! As you warned, it did not work for the large dataset, but I am able to implement it for another part of the code I am working on. Thank you.
